# Regex and/or sed to replace lowercase

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with a single column of data.  Take the following data for example

```
united states
germany
france
canada
```

Of which I am trying to generate all possible mixed case variations.  For example the new file might look like this

```
United states
uNited states
unIted states
uniTed states
unitEd states
uniteD stated
united States
united sTates
united stAtes
united staTes
united statEs
united stateS
UNited states
```

And so on until all possible case variations of each word have been generated.

Given the above input and expected output I have three questions

1. Is regex and sed the right tool for this job?
2. What alternatives do I have to regex and sed for this task?
3. If I did use regex and sed what might the correct syntax look like?

Comment: The description and the sample output seem to contradict. At least if the sample output is complete. You want all possible case variations, including `UnItEd StAtEs`? Or just one upper case in each line?

Comment: Is lowercase-only + whitespace guaranteed for the input?

Comment: Nicely written question for a newbie ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No

2) Awk and substr()

3) You wouldn't

Start with this:

```
$ echo 'foo' |
awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=length($0);i++) {
        print substr($0,1,i-1) toupper(substr($0,i,1)) substr($0,i+1)
    }
}'
Foo
fOo
foO
```

and massage to suit with the obvious logic.

Comment: Can you elaborate your "1) No" ?

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything other than s/old/new/ you should be using awk for simplicity, clarity, robustness, efficiency, portability and every other desirable attribute of software. Your requirements cannot be satisfied by simply s/old/new/ so therefore sed is not the right tool for this job. All sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) are used today just for the mental exercise, not for production software as they became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Comment: And that is me, not reading (or understanding) all of your answer. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of sed.

1) Yes.  (e.g. GNU sed version 4.2.1)
2) Maybe awk, perl
3) See code below

```
sed -E "s/^.*$/\n&#\n/;:a;s/\n([^#\n]*)([^#\n])#([^#\n]*)\n/\n\1#\u\2\3\n\1#\l\2\3\n/;ta;s/(^\n#|\n$)//g;s/\n#/\n/g;"
```

This does assume that "#" is not part of the strings found in the file.

- create a certain pattern
  (start and end with newline; mark the cursor with `#`)
- start a loop

  - replace text between newlines and containing the cursor by same text twice,
    once with uppercase before cursor, once with lower case
  - move cursor one towards the start
  - loop if that replaced something
- remove newlines at start and end and cursors

Note that `#` is not special. It just needs to be a character wich will not occur in input and not in desired output. Hopefully you can find a special character.
If you can have all characters, it gets complicated. Look at the comments to this answer. There probably is a discussion going on.

Output (for input "foo"):

```
FOO
fOO
FoO
foO
FOo
fOo
Foo
foo
```

Comment: For the sake of learning, what if I did have # as part of the string?

Comment: My respect for that.

Comment: @user316114 Looks like there is no simple generic solution for troublesome letters. I assume that the "use other non-occurring letter" I edited into the answer is not satisfying you. If you create a question, it could get interesting, or at least attract pointers to an answer.